# PHP5 $_FILES[][] notice error - Undefined

Tags: php, file, file-upload, notice

I am trying to upload a file to my server using php5 script. And I am receiving an notice error `Undefined index: qqfile`.

```
$_FILES['qqfile']['tmp_name']
```

But I don't know how it is not defined from the previous script. The "tmp_name" is there in the array, but qqfile is showing UnDefined...

Comment: Have you figured this out, I am having some oddness with this as well

Answer (score 2):

if `$_FILES['qqfile']` doesn't exist, then neither could `['tmp_name']`. Do a `var_dump($_FILES)` to see what's really in there. Note that if your file upload form doesn't haven the following format, the file upload will NOT work:

```
<form action="yourscript.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ MUST BE present
```

Comment: Also note that an entry will not exist in `$_FILES` if the file was larger than [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)... And I think it's also gone if the file exceeded `upload_max_filesize` too.

In other words, you **must** check `array_key_exists("qqfile",$_FILES)` after the form post, because there's *always* something that can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Most of time it's because the file uploaded is greater than the limit setted into php.ini.

Try to upload a small file and see if it's works.

Btw there isn't any "undefined" type in PHP.  And it's impossible that exists `$_FILES['qqfile']['tmp_name']` but not only `$_FILES['qqfile']`

Regards php.ini you should see the value of:

```
ini_set('post_max_size',); 
ini_set('upload_max_filesize',); 
ini_set('max_input_time', );
```

Are you sure you have a

```
<input type="file" name="qqfile" />
```

?

Comment: I uploaded a 131kb file and received an error. And php.ini is set to upload_max_filesize = 128M

Comment: @justin: ok then the problem isn't php.ini. Are your sure you are using the right enctype and the name of your `<input is name="qqfile"` ?